# How to avoid SonarQube issue about abstract exceptions?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sequence, adroitlogic

I am using SonarQube for my code quality analysis. I am coding in java with the use of `AbstractJavaSequence` from AdroidLogic API.

Many of my project classes extend this class and override execute method which by default declare `throws Exception`. The SonarQube analysis raises an issue, stating that the class uses a generic exception instead of specific one.

How can I resolve this SonarQube issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the method you are overriding `throws Exception`, it doesn't mean you have to.

You are free to not declare that you throw any exceptions at all, or to throw specific exceptions instead:

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    abstract void doSomething() throws Exception;
}
```

These are all valid (obviously, not all at once):

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public void doSomething() {
    }

    public void doSomething() throws MyException {
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

There's no reason for you to carry on their bad practices.

Comment: You could maybe link to/quote from [JLS Sec 8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3), which describes this.